# Way for moving stored procedure from Firebird to SQL Server

Tags: sql-server-2008, stored-procedures, firebird

**I have working SP on Firebird and can'not find the way to translate code to MS SQL server SP**

here is the code:

I have one table to get data from.
One fields called "iznos" for data summary and one field for recognite diference for summary by category

```
create or alter procedure SOME_PROCEDURE (  
      B_Date date,  
      E_Date date)  

returns(  
      Dat date,  
      Value1 decimal(18,2),  
      Value2 decimal(18,2),  
      Value3 (18,2))  
AS  

BEGIN  
    FOR   
    SELECT gk.date  
    FROM gk 
    WHERE  
        gk.date BETWEEN :B_Date AND :E_Date  
    GROUP BY 1  
    INTO :Dat  
    DO  
    BEGIN  
        /* Value 1 */  
        SELECT sum(iznos) from gk where gk.category=1 and gk.datum=:Dat  
        INTO :Value1;  
        /* Value 2 */  
        SELECT sum(iznos) from gk where gk.category=2 and gk.datum=:Dat  
        INTO :Value2;  
        /* Value 3 */  
        SELECT sum(iznos) from gk where gk.category=3 and gk.datum=:Dat  
        INTO :Value3;  
        suspend;  
    end  
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can solve this using [`PIVOT`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410%28v=sql.105%29.aspx):

```
select datum, [1] as Value1, [2] as Value2, [3] as Value3
from (
    select datum, category, iznos 
    from gk 
    where datum between @B_Date AND @E_Date 
) as src
pivot (
    sum(src.iznos)
    for src.category in ([1], [2], [3])
) as pvt
```

This doesn't have the exact same effect as the Firebird stored procedure though, because that is returning a row for each row in `gk`. If you want to have the exact same result, you may have to join `gk` to the above query.

If you intend to use this stored procedure in a select (which is possible in Firebird, but not in SQL Server), then you need to convert it to a [table-valued user-defined function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191320%28v=sql.110%29.aspx#TVF).

You could also create a view instead. In that case the `where` clause would need to be removed.

Small example in TSQL:

```
create table #example (
   datum date,
   category int,
   val int
);

insert into #example(datum, category, val) values
    ('2015-07-24', 1, 1),
    ('2015-07-24', 2, 1),
    ('2015-07-24', 3, 1),
    ('2015-07-24', 1, 1),
    ('2015-07-24', 2, 1),
    ('2015-07-25', 3, 1);

select datum, [1] as Value1, [2] as Value2, [3] as Value3
from (
    select datum, category, val 
    from #example 
) as src
pivot (
    sum(src.val)
    for src.category in ([1], [2], [3])
) as pvt;

drop table #example;
```

Comment: **Thanks mate!** I need to create stored-procedure which returns one row for every date between two dates ex, B_Date and E_Date.

Comment: @Slavica I had missed the `for select` part due to the indenting. You can easily change the PIVOT example to do exactly that. I will update my answer shortly.

Comment: this code is working but only if i delete "datum" in first line of code and have table without datum column. With this code i have error on compile window with message:   The multi-part identifier "dbo.GK.DATUM" could not be bound.

Comment: @slavica It works fine for me on SQL Server 2012. I added a piece of example TSQL I used.

Comment: @ Mark Rotteveel - my fault! I need result grouped by date. Anyway thanks. U help me a lot and save my time against your. Thanks again.

Comment: @Slavica The result is already grouped by date. That is what the `pivot` part does, unless you have a `date` and a `datum` column, in which case you can probably solve it by joining the result of the pivot with `gk` again, although then I don't really understand your datamodel.